# i get error when i logout from the laravel auth

Tags: php, laravel

i get error when i logout in laravel. because there is no id.
error show this code.

```
<a href="/user/{{Auth::user()->id}}">Profilim</a>
```

***here is error***

***Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\mit\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)***

***i know it give this error because when i logout "User()->id", has no value and it give me error***

***how can i solve it?***

Comment: You could not show that line if `Auth::user()` returns null. I assume this is for the profile, and a logged out user won't have acces to it's profile.

Comment: how can i solve that? or how i tell if has  ?

Comment: Well, you use a conditionnal to check if the value of `Auth::user()` is null ? There is a ton of example on how to use conditionnal online...

Answer (score 1):

You can use Blade's `@auth` directive to prevent that link from rendering when logged out:

```
@auth
<a href="/user/{{Auth::user()->id}}">Profilim</a>
@endauth
```